# How to measure how 'well' I am matching Google keywords?

Tags: classification, text-mining, natural-language

For google keywords you can bid on a broad match. For example let's say I bid on the keyword 'best hamburger' and somebody searches 'What sort of beef makes the best hamburger?' and 'eat best hamburger'.

Both would be matches, but 'eat best hamburger' would be a better 'match'. I.E. - Their intent aligns more closely with why I am bidding on these keywords. I understand this is a pretty open ended question but what are some methods to begin tackling a problem like this? I want to compare the 'goodness' of the matching of my broad match Google keywords.

Comment: It certainly is an open ended question; it also sounds very interesting. Can you add more detail regarding what you have tried or even what you have thought of trying?